# Variadic template tensor class

Tags: c++, hpc

I'm trying to make a variadic template tensor class with as template parameters a type and a set of dimensions.

For example creating an array of 13 floats would use `Tensor<float, 13> a;` and creating a 3rd order 3 by 4 by 5 tensor of doubles would use `Tensor<double, 3, 4, 5> b;`. This is for a HPC application. Ultimately all elements need to append in memory, and the whole object should be allocated at once.

The object `Tensor<double, 3, 4, 5>` would have one field of type `std::array<Tensor<double, 3, 4>, 5>` maybe.

I'm having issues recursively defining this type with a variadic template. I'm currently trying the following code, but it doesn't compile, and have run out of ideas. I think adding a specialization template for `sizeof(n) == 0` is a step in the right direction, but no luck.

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, int m, int ...n>
class Tensor {
public:
    std::array<Tensor<T, n>, m> a;
};
```

Alternatively `a` could just be a c-type array of whatever size is the product of the elements in `n`. How would I compute that product while still keeping the `Tensor<double, 3, 4, 5> b;` syntax for an uninitialized tensor?

Solution:

`std::array<Tensor<T, n>, m> a;` should be `std::array<Tensor<T, n...>, m> a;` and the class should be redefined so that e.g. `Tensor<float, 3>` is legal.

Comment: maybe some ...'s on line 6?  The error message literally says that: source>:6:33: error: parameter packs not expanded with '...': https://godbolt.org/z/cq4Wd9

Comment: Didn't know what that compiler error ment, thanks. Now it's failing because Tensor<T, 3> can't be created since it has too few arguments, but should be able to fix that.

Comment: Please consider adding an actual [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), if you have already found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::array<Tensor<T, n>, m> a;` should be `std::array<Tensor<T, n...>, m> a;` and the class should be redefined so that e.g. `Tensor<float, 3>` is legal.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to expand the parameter pack.

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, int m, int ...n>
class Tensor {
public:
    std::array<Tensor<T, n...>, m> a;
};
```